# Create GoogleMaps markers from a Vuex store?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, object, vue.js, vue-cli

I want to create a map using several markers which are in a Vuex store loading a Json file.

I am new to VueJS and don't get how to import the data in the store to use it in the mounted hook of my GoogleMap component.

I have already looked for a solution or a piece of code which could give me an idea and found nothing. New to Vue and Google Maps, I am stuck on this problem.

I get my data from the store with:

```
computed: {
      displayRestaurantInfo() {
        return this.$store.getters.getRestaurantInfo;
      }
    }
```

And have created a function in the mounted hook of my component (but nothing I have tried works):

```
pushMarkersCoordinates => {

      }
```

An extract of the JSON file if necessary:

```
[
  {
    "restaurantName": "Le Select",
    "address": "99 Boulevard du Montparnasse, 75006 Paris",
    "description": "Très bon restaurant de Plancha, cuisine généreuse",
    "lat": 48.842702,
    "long": 2.328434,
    "ratings": [
      {
        "stars": 4,
        "author": "Marc",
        "date": "15/02/2017",
        "comment": "Un excellent restaurant, j'y reviendrai ! Par contre il vaut mieux aimer la viande."
         },
      {
        "stars": 5,
        "author": "Sylvain",
        "date": "15/05/2017",
        "comment": "Tout simplement mon restaurant préféré !"
         },
      {
        "stars": 5,
        "author": "Patrick",
        "date": "15/11/2017",
        "comment": "Généreux !!! Rien à dire de plus."
         },
      {
        "stars": 4,
        "author": "Marc",
        "date": "15/01/2018",
        "comment": "Un excellent restaurant, j'y reviendrai ! Par contre il vaut mieux aimer la viande."
         },
      {
        "stars": 5,
        "author": "Sylvain",
        "date": "15/04/2018",
        "comment": "Tout simplement mon restaurant préféré !"
         },
      {
        "stars": 5,
        "author": "Patrick",
        "date": "15/08/2018",
        "comment": "Généreux !!! Rien à dire de plus."
         }
      ]
   },
  {
    "restaurantName": "L'Atelier",
    "address": "95 Boulevard du Montparnasse, 75006 Paris",
    "description": "Des pizzas comme en Italie, fine et gourmande",
    "lat": 48.842751,
    "long": 2.328118,
    "ratings": [
      {
        "stars": 5,
        "author": "Elodie",
        "date": "15/02/2017",
        "comment": "Une minuscule pizzeria délicieuse cachée juste à côté du Sacré choeur !"
         },
      {
        "stars": 3,
        "author": "Paul",
        "date": "15/05/2017",
        "comment": "J'ai trouvé ça correct, sans plus"
         },
      {
        "stars": 2,
        "author": "Yasmine",
        "date": "15/11/2017",
        "comment": "Pâtes froides !"
         },
      {
        "stars": 5,
        "author": "Elodie",
        "date": "15/01/2018",
        "comment": "Une minuscule pizzeria délicieuse cachée juste à côté du Sacré choeur !"
         },
      {
        "stars": 3,
        "author": "Paul",
        "date": "15/04/2018",
        "comment": "J'ai trouvé ça correct, sans plus"
         },
      {
        "stars": 2,
        "author": "Yasmine",
        "date": "15/08/2018",
        "comment": "Pâtes froides !"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

The code in the store.js file:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
const axios = require('axios');

Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    data: [],
  },
  getters: {
    getRestaurantInfo: state => {
      const restaurantList = state.data;

      return restaurantList.map((restaurant) => {
        const sum = restaurant.ratings.reduce((acc, rating) => {
          return acc + rating.stars;
        }, 0);
        return {
          ...restaurant,
          averageRating: Math.round(sum / restaurant.ratings.length),
        }
      })
    }, 
    getComments: state => {
      console.log(state);
      return (restaurantID) => {
        const restaurant = state.data[restaurantID];
        return restaurant.ratings;
      }

    }
  },
  mutations: {
    setData: (state, {info}) => {
      state.data = info;
    }
  },
  actions: {
    getData: async function (context) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        axios.get('http://localhost:8080/restaurantList.json').then((response) => {
          context.commit('setData', {
            info: response.data});
          return true;
        }, (err) => {
          console.log(err);
          return false;
        });
      }, 500)
    }
  }
});

//callJSON: state => {
//  axios
//    .get('http://localhost:8080/restaurantList.json')
//    .then(response => (state.info = response.data))
//    .catch(function (error) {
//      if (error.response) {
//        console.log(error.response.data);
//        console.log(error.response.status);
//        console.log(error.response.headers);
//      } else if (error.request) {
//        console.log(error.request);
//      } else {
//        console.log('Error', error.message);
//      }
//    })
//    .then(function () {
//
//    });
//},
```

The code in the GoogleMap component:

```
<template>
  <div class="main" ref="autreRef">
    <div class="google-map" v-bind:id="mapName" ref="mainMap">
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  //  import mapInterface from '../../interfaces/mapInterface.js'
  const GoogleMapsLoader = require('google-maps');
  GoogleMapsLoader.KEY = '';

  export default {
    name: 'google-map',
    props: ['name'],
    data: function() {
      return {
        mapName: this.name + "-map",
        markerCoordinates: [{
          latitude: 48.842492,
          longitude: 2.328300
        }],
        map: null,
        bounds: null,
        markers: [],
        infoWindow: null,
        position: {
          lat: null,
          lng: null
        }
      }
    },

    mounted: function() {
      GoogleMapsLoader.load((google) => {
          this.bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
          const element = this.$refs.mainMap
          this.infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
          const mapCentre = this.markerCoordinates[0]
          const options = {
            zoom: 18,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(mapCentre.latitude, mapCentre.longitude)
          }
          this.map = new google.maps.Map(element, options);

          this.markerCoordinates.forEach((coord) => {
            //        const marker = mapInterface.createMarker(coord)
            const position = new google.maps.LatLng(coord.latitude, coord.longitude);
            const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position,
              map: this.map
            });
            this.markers.push(marker)
            // Pour avoir tous les marqueurs sur la map si plusieurs marqueurs
            //        this.map.fitBounds(this.bounds.extend(position))
          });
          if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
              const pos = {
                lat: position.coords.latitude,
                lng: position.coords.longitude
              };

              this.infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
              this.infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
              this.infoWindow.open(this.map);
              this.map.setCenter(pos);
            }, function() {
              handleLocationError(true, this.infoWindow, this.map.getCenter());
            });
          } else {
            // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
            handleLocationError(false, this.infoWindow, this.map.getCenter());
          }
        })
    },
    computed: {
      displayRestaurantInfo() {
        return this.$store.getters.getRestaurantInfo;
      }
    }
  };
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
  .google-map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 2px solid #26A65B;
    border-radius: 2rem;
  }
</style>
```

I want to understand how to use data from the store (or other components indirectly) in the mounted hook (or other hooks indirectly).
For this project, to be able to create several markers.
Thanks.

Comment: I hope that you haven't posted your real Google App key... if yes, then I advise you to change it immediately to an "example" or "YOUR_GOOGLE_API_KEY".

Comment: If you haven't done so, install the Vue devtools for Chrome. With that a new item appears in the dev console (Vue), where you can check templates, Vuex stores, etc. I'd check what's in the store when the **axios** request is done. Then you can look at the **GoogleMap** component, if that has "imported" the data from the store correctly.